# Deployment on JBoss with Intellij partially fails

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, jboss7.x, wicket, jrebel

The jboss (7.1.1) jrebel (6) deployment starts twice and at the second time it throw the exception "Child container with name /zorro already exists". After that the application is up and running but Intellij (14) shows a "explanation mark" at the deployment.

Why is the deployment started twice?

```
11:34:56,686 INFO  [org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller] (MSC service thread 1-4) Creating JAXBContext with context path ******
11:34:58,772 INFO  [org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter] (MSC service thread 1-4) Could not detect RMI registry - creating new one
11:34:58,806 INFO  [org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter] (MSC service thread 1-4) Binding service '******' to RMI registry: RegistryImpl[UnicastServerRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[*********](local),objID:[0:0:0, 0]]]]
11:34:58,974 INFO  [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] (MSC service thread 1-4) Using DataSource [org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource@1d74e26f] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
11:34:59,063 INFO  [waffle.servlet.spi.SecurityFilterProviderCollection] (MSC service thread 1-4) using 'waffle.servlet.spi.NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider'
11:34:59,064 INFO  [waffle.servlet.spi.SecurityFilterProviderCollection] (MSC service thread 1-4) using 'waffle.servlet.spi.BasicSecurityFilterProvider'
11:34:59,247 INFO  [org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain] (MSC service thread 1-4) Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@3b0acc54, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@41ecbd14, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@a18759e, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@4bd1dd3f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@3f1479fc, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@5954afbe, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@46de10c3, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@1d1e968e]
11:35:00,269 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-4) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 13769 ms
11:35:00,451 INFO  [org.apache.wicket.util.file.WebXmlFile] (MSC service thread 1-4) web.xml: url mapping found for filter with name wicketFilter: [/*]
11:35:00,631 INFO  [org.apache.wicket.Application] (MSC service thread 1-4) [wicketFilter] init: Wicket core library initializer
11:35:00,634 INFO  [org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface] (MSC service thread 1-4) registered listener interface [RequestListenerInterface name=IBehaviorListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener.onRequest()]
11:35:00,643 INFO  [org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface] (MSC service thread 1-4) registered listener interface [RequestListenerInterface name=IFormSubmitListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IFormSubmitListener.onFormSubmitted()]
11:35:00,644 INFO  [org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface] (MSC service thread 1-4) registered listener interface [RequestListenerInterface name=ILinkListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.ILinkListener.onLinkClicked()]
11:35:00,645 INFO  [org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface] (MSC service thread 1-4) registered listener interface [RequestListenerInterface name=IOnChangeListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IOnChangeListener.onSelectionChanged()]
11:35:00,646 INFO  [org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface] (MSC service thread 1-4) registered listener interface [RequestListenerInterface name=IRedirectListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.IRedirectListener.onRedirect()]
11:35:00,648 INFO  [org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface] (MSC service thread 1-4) registered listener interface [RequestListenerInterface name=IResourceListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.IResourceListener.onResourceRequested()]
11:35:00,649 INFO  [org.apache.wicket.Application] (MSC service thread 1-4) [wicketFilter] init: DevUtils DebugBar Initializer
11:35:00,656 INFO  [org.apache.wicket.Application] (MSC service thread 1-4) [wicketFilter] init: Wicket extensions initializer
11:35:00,668 INFO  [org.apache.wicket.Application] (MSC service thread 1-4) [wicketFilter] init: wicket.contrib.tinymce.TinyMceInitializer@5c899de4
11:35:02,361 INFO  [org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebApplication] (MSC service thread 1-4) [wicketFilter] Started Wicket version 6.17.0 in DEVELOPMENT mode
11:35:02,362 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-4) ********************************************************************
11:35:02,362 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-4) *** WARNING: Wicket is running in DEVELOPMENT mode.              ***
11:35:02,362 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-4) ***                               ^^^^^^^^^^^                    ***
11:35:02,362 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-4) *** Do NOT deploy to your live server(s) without changing this.  ***
11:35:02,363 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-4) *** See Application#getConfigurationType() for more information. ***
11:35:02,363 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-4) ********************************************************************
11:35:02,411 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /zorro
11:35:02,421 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
11:35:02,422 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 36356ms - Started 232 of 309 services (76 services are passive or on-demand)
11:35:02,575 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "zorro-web.war"
11:35:02,612 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "zorro-web-1.18.5-SNAPSHOT.war"
11:35:17,931 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054: Could not find default constructor for class org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription$DefaultComponentConfigurator.configure(ComponentDescription.java:606)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:81)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]

11:35:18,264 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./zorro: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./zorro: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Child container with name /zorro already exists
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:804)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:792)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:356)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebContextInjector.inject(WebContextInjector.java:62)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebContextInjector.inject(WebContextInjector.java:38)
    at org.jboss.msc.inject.CastingInjector.inject(CastingInjector.java:55) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.doInject(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1549) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.access$1900(ServiceControllerImpl.java:49) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.performInjections(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1780) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1741) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    ... 3 more

11:35:18,706 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "zorro-web-1.18.5-SNAPSHOT.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./zorro" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./zorro: Failed to start service"}}
11:35:19,393 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment zorro-web-1.18.5-SNAPSHOT.war in 685ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the deployment artifact from 'war' to 'war exploded' did the job.